# How to extract headline titles followed by respective text from Wikipedia

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I am trying to use Jsoup in order to extract text from Wikipedia articles.

My idea is to simply extract every headline, and their respective text paragraphs.

I am having some trouble understanding how I can take only the specific text of each section, here's what I have:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

String url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein";
Document doc;

try {
    doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    doc = Jsoup.parse(doc.toString());

    Elements titles = doc.select(".mw-headline");
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt"));
    System.setOut(out);

    for(Element h3 : doc.select(".mw-headline")) 
    {
        String title = h3.text();

        String titleID = h3.id();

        Elements paragraphs = doc.select("p#"+titleID);

        //Element  nextEle=h3.nextElementSibling();

        System.out.println(title);
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(titleID);
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.println(paragraphs.text());
        System.out.print("\n");
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("deu merda");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

With this I can extract every headline, but I can't get how I would get the text from each section to print it accordingly. I was thinking maybe with the headline's ID, but no dice.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the tag structure of the page (if any), that could be complicated.  A better alternative could be to iterate on all the elements, detecting headlines.  Every time you detect a new headline (or you reach the end of the elements), it means a new headline.  All elements up to here belong to the previous headline (or to the "header" of the article if there is no previous headline).

Comment: Yeah I though of that, the line that is commented is a leftover from a try of iterating over the elements. I couldn't do it at first and tried to find another way, but I guess I'll try it again. Thanks!